# Print out how much males and female there are in foreach loop

Tags: php

I need to get printed out in an echo how much males(m) there are and how much females(v) there are. I'm pretty new to PHP so sorry i don't understand this simple stuff but i really cant find it online.

This is the array

```
$aGente = array('jan'=> 'm', 'alice'=> 'v', 'veronica'=> 'v', 'herman'=> 'm','maria'=> 'v', 'angelica' => 'v' , 'nancy' => 'v', 'pieter' => 'm');
```

This is what i have so far:

```
foreach($aGente as $k => $v){
    if($k => $v){
        echo $v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is actually count and keep the tally in variables then echo the totals.

```
$numMales = 0;
$numFemales = 0;
foreach($aGente as $k => $v){
    if($v == "m"){
        $numMales++;
    } else if($v == "v") {
        $numFemales++;
    }
}
echo "You have " . $numMales . " males and " . $numFemales . " females."
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use array_keys php function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

using the second parameter, you can precise a search value.

example:

```
$aGente = array('jan'=> 'm', 'alice'=> 'v', 'veronica'=> 'v', 'herman'=> 'm','maria'=> 'v', 'angelica' => 'v' , 'nancy' => 'v', 'pieter' => 'm');
$all_v = array_keys($aGente, 'v');
$all_m = array_keys($aGente, 'm');
echo count($all_v); // gives the number of v
echo count($all_m); // gives the number of m
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_count_values function.

```
$aGente = array('jan'=> 'm', 'alice'=> 'v', 'veronica'=> 'v', 'herman'=> 'm','maria'=> 'v', 'angelica' => 'v' , 'nancy' => 'v', 'pieter' => 'm');

$count =array_count_values($aGente);

echo "Male Count =>".$count['m'];
echo "<br>";
echo "Female Count =>".$count['v'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Using of `array_count_values` function would be, probably, the simplest way in such case:

```
$genders = array_count_values($aGente);
echo "Males: ". $genders['m']. PHP_EOL . "Females: ". $genders['v'];
```

The output:

```
Males: 3
Females: 5
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php